# Sending data from child activity to the main one

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

After trying lot of things found here, nothing worked.

To make it simple :

I have a main activity with a button.

I have a **"child"** activity with **2 text fields** and a **button**.

When I click the **main activity button**, the **child activity** opens (it works). Then I put some text to the **two text fields** and when I click the **button** I want the data from the text fields to be transfered to the **main activity**, and I can't get this working.

Here is my main activity code

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAddBib;



public final static int REQUEST_CODE_B = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


    btnAddBib = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddBib);

    btnAddBib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,REQUEST_CODE_B);

        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_B:
            String Qte = data.getStringExtra("qte");
            String Time = data.getStringExtra("time");


            if (Qte != null && !Qte.isEmpty() && Time != null && !Time.isEmpty()) {
                final SQLiteDatabase dbBib;
                dbBib = openOrCreateDatabase("bibi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                dbBib.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bibi(time VARCHAR, qte VARCHAR);");
                dbBib.execSQL("INSERT INTO bibi VALUES ('" + Time + "','" +
                        Qte + "')");


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bibi bien enregistré",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail get extraData",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

           break;
    }
}
```

And the child activity code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ajouter_bibi);

    btnValideBib = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnValideBib);
    btnValideBib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_biberon);

    txtTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    txtQte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQte);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hh = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int mm = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    txtTime.setText(hh + ":" + mm);

    btnValideBib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent backIntent = new Intent();
            backIntent.putExtra("qte", txtQte.getText());
            backIntent.putExtra("time", txtTime.getText());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, backIntent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

The problem :

In the main activity, when I want to get back my Extra Strings I have null fields.

```
        String Qte = data.getStringExtra("qte");
        String Time = data.getStringExtra("time");
```

What is wrong with it ?

Thanks!

Comment: switch(requestCode) -> check for resultCode.

Comment: what is an **exact** signature of `backIntent.putExtra` methods you use to put extras? in other words: do you use putExtra(String name, int value) or putExtra(String name, char value) or what?

Comment: @pskink you were on the good way. Clairvoyant solved it! Thanks anyway

Comment: it is not child activity btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code :

```
backIntent.putExtra("qte", txtQte.getText());
backIntent.putExtra("time", txtTime.getText());
```

to below code:

```
backIntent.putExtra("qte", txtQte.getText().toString()); //append .toString() method
backIntent.putExtra("time", txtTime.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!! First time using StackOverFlow and got the answer in a few minutes! As it was text fields I though there were no need to add toString() method. Thanks!

Comment: You need to add **toString()** which converts it to **String**. And please upvote if your problem solved that helped me also.

Comment: Upvoted but I do not have not enough reputation points so that my vote can be displayed!